# Font Awesome is displaying a different version of an icon depending on the page

Tags: css, wordpress, icons

I'm having a problem on with a Wordpress website I'm putting together for a friend. For some reason, FontAwesome displays one version of its Instagram icon in the header when on her index page, but another when on any other page on the website.

Example...

Her index page: http://deepwoods.design/wechling/

Another page: http://deepwoods.design/wechling/weddings/

They're both Instagram icons, but one seems to be from an older version of FontAwesome? I checked in several different browsers but the issue persists in all of them. On mobile, the same issue occurs in every browser but Safari, which behaves (but Safari on my Windows desktop does have the problem). So, I'm not sure if it's related to browsers or not. If anyone could lend a hand with a solution, that would be great :)! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you call one CSS file in first page and don't call it in second page. The following CSS file:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wds_font-awesome-css'  href='http://deepwoods.design/wechling/wp-content/plugins/slider-wd/css/font-awesome-4.0.1/font-awesome.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Just add above code into `head` of second page too.

Comment: You are the bee's knees! I didn't think to check if one of the plugins was causing shenanigans to happen. Thank you!